# Animating a line in vpython

Tags: python, python-2.7, vpython

I am trying to animate a line, by incrementing its length in 7 steps. But when I compile this code, I see only a blank screen.

```
import time
from visual import *
rod = cylinder (length=6, color=color.red, radius=.5, pos=(-3,-2,0))
i=0
while(i<7):
  rate(10)
  rod.length=i
  time.sleep(1)
  i+=1
```

In order to see the process in slow-motion, I added sleep time of 1 sec.
Please correct me if am wrong...

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from visual import *
rod = cylinder (length=6, color=color.red, radius=.5, pos=(-3,-2,0))
i=0
while(i<7):
  rate(2)
  rod.length=rod.length-1
  i+=1
  #time.sleep(1)
  if rod.length==0:
      break
```